# How to correct obsolete code for creating Canvas

Tags: c#, itext7

This code using *iText7* runs. It copies a PDF file and, on the copy, prints a rectangle on top of page 1 with a red border around a text id or message:

```cs
        public static void InsertIdPdf(string sourceFilename, string targetFilename, string idText)
        {
            if (idText.Length > 0)
            {
                PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFilename));
                PdfDocument targetPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(targetFilename));

                sourcePdf.CopyPagesTo(1, sourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages(), targetPdf);
                Document document = new Document(targetPdf, new PageSize(PageSize.A4));

                PdfPage firstPage = targetPdf.GetFirstPage();
                iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle pageSize = firstPage.GetCropBox().MoveUp(4);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(new PdfCanvas(firstPage, true), targetPdf, pageSize);

                PdfFont idFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
                Style idStyle = new Style()
                    .SetFont(idFont)
                    .SetFontSize(8)
                    .SetPaddingRight(3)
                    .SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.RIGHT)
                    .SetBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);

                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(idText)
                    .SetBorder(new SolidBorder(ColorConstants.RED, (float)0.7))
                    .AddStyle(idStyle);
                IRenderer renderer = paragraph.CreateRendererSubTree();
                renderer.SetParent(document.GetRenderer()).Layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(1, pageSize)));

                canvas.Add(paragraph);
                document.Close();
                sourcePdf.Close();
                targetPdf.Close();
            }
        }
```

However, iText7 claims this line to be *obsolete* because the last argument, the Rectangle, may be removed in a future version:

```cs
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(new PdfCanvas(firstPage, true), targetPdf, pageSize);
```

I've tried to adjust the line, removing `pageSize` to satisfy iText7, but then the rectangle will print *below* the normal text on the page and *flipped (mirrored) vertically*.

1. So, how to adjust the line to not be obsolete and still print the rectangle at the top?

Also, notice the `.MoveUp(4)` for `pageSize`. The value **4** is an empiric value that moves the rectangle to the absolute top of the page. If omitted, the rectangle will be positioned with a small gab to the top of the page. This gab is independent of the font size.

2. So, why **4**? I dislike magic numbers and would prefer a calculated value. What expression could be used to calculate this value?

Reference is the two questions here at SO:

[Adding page number text to pdf copy gets flipped/mirrored with iText7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743566/adding-page-number-text-to-pdf-copy-gets-flipped-mirrored-with-itext-7)

[iText7: How to get the real width of a Paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61911094/itext7-how-to-get-the-real-width-of-a-paragraph)

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this but I couldn't be able to. Given code is already producing a 180degrees rotated page and no rectangle is drawn.

Comment: @HasanManzak et al: Please notice my [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64972425/what-value-to-use-for-moveup-of-canvas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this but I am now. I think it was something about the printable area of the document I was trying.

That's aside, the adjustment of the obsolete part is pretty simple. Just change

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(new PdfCanvas(firstPage, true), targetPdf, pageSize);
```

to

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(new PdfCanvas(firstPage, true), pageSize);
```

The obsoletion is the `pdfDocument` parameter.

About the magic number `4`. I think it is about the DPI, I really don't know what it is. But the most relevant resource I could find is already in the community: [Points -> pixels iText (im)precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18078590/points-pixels-itext-imprecision)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the obsolete part. That runs nicely. However, for the other part, I don't believe it is related to the DPI as it is consistent when enlarging the view. As you have promptly answered the first part, I think I'll post a new question with some screen shots for the second part.