# iText7 how to set an existing PDF document's margin and save the newly created file?

Tags: c#, pdf, margin, itext7

I'm using iText7 in C# and I have a PDF file in which I have to change the margin programmatically.
I've tried out everything with not much success, the only thing that *kinda* worked for me is this snippet of code

```
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFile), new PdfWriter(destinationFile));
float margin = 30;

for (int i = 0; i < pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.GetPage(i+1);
    Rectangle mediaBox = page.GetMediaBox();
    Rectangle newMediabox = new Rectangle(mediaBox.GetLeft() - margin, mediaBox.GetBottom() + margin, mediaBox.GetWidth(), mediaBox.GetHeight());
    page.SetMediaBox(newMediabox);
}

pdfDoc.Close();
```

I said **kinda**, because all it does is pushing the content of the PDF file.

Is there any way I can change the margin of an existing PDF file?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### UPDATE

I have tried Gustav's answer, but nothing changed
Here is my code:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    RegisterPdfImproved(source, target);
}

public static void RegisterPdfImproved(string sourceFilename, string targetFilename)
{
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFilename), new PdfWriter(targetFilename)))
    using (Document document = new Document(pdf))
    {
        document.SetMargins(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000);
        //Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(registration).AddStyle(RegistrationStyle()).SetMarginTop(0);
        //document.Add(paragraph);
    }
}

private static Style RegistrationStyle()
{
    // Fixed design values for font and rectangle.
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
    const float fontSize = 8F;
    const float rightPadding = 3F;
    TextAlignment textAlignment = TextAlignment.RIGHT;
    iText.Kernel.Colors.Color borderColor = ColorConstants.RED;
    iText.Kernel.Colors.Color fillColor = ColorConstants.WHITE;
    const float borderWidth = 0.7F;

    Style style = new Style()
        .SetFont(font)
        .SetFontSize(fontSize)
        .SetPaddingRight(rightPadding)
        .SetTextAlignment(textAlignment)
        .SetBackgroundColor(fillColor)
        .SetBorder(new SolidBorder(borderColor, borderWidth));

    return style;
}
```

Maybe I did soemthing wrong?

Comment: In [a question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65303457/3527297) @mkl helped me setting the margins of an existing document (and of a paragraph).

Comment: Thank you @Gustav for your answer! I tried it but didnt work, I updated my code, maybe 
 I did something wrong there, could you check it please?
I would be in your debt!

Comment: What exactly is your expectation? Do you want to add/remove margin space, leaving the content as is but resizing the page? Or do you want the page size to remain the same and resize the page content to take less or more space? And in the latter case, shall the content be scaled? Or re-layout-ed?

Comment: @mkl
I want the page size to remain the same and resize the page content to take less or more space while it remains as much as scaled as it can be.
Or at least I belive that's what margins do. I'm sorry if I'm not expressing myself precisely, I'm really new to this
Thank you for helping me tho :)

Comment: So you want to change the space available to the content but not scale the content. Thus, you want to change the layout of contents. E.g. if the space gets less wide, lines must be broken. If the space gets less altogether, content must be moved to the next page. Correct?

Comment: @mkl Yes, you are 100% correct

Comment: That's unfortunate. In general pdfs don't contain machine readable information required for that. E.g. there usually is no information in a pdf where some paragraph starts and stops, how large margins are, what is header or footer, background material or main content. So there is no obvious way to do what you want for generic pdfs. One can try and develop heuristics, analyze the pages by their appearance, but that is beyond the focus of a general purpose pdf library. Actually that might be what a separate library project built on top of itext might be about.

Comment: And is there a way to achieve a similar effect?

Comment: *"And is there a way to achieve a similar effect?"* - As described above, in general the recognition of the role of text pieces and layout dependent values is guesswork. So achieving any *similar effect* requiring knowledge thereof is in general complicated and/or error-prone. Your question appears to be about a single PDF only, though, so if you can share it, people here can try and find out whether it does offer enough information to achieve your goal by short cut. Also you can ponder whether the scaling alternative would be an option.

Comment: @mkl Here is the test pdf, but this is just a **test** pdf. Maybe I wan't to use the program on some other one's too. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1thOnWnF6usYcHW7aWwxupWSRbCvlmzm8/view?usp=sharing The only goal now is to add space on the top, right, bottom and left side of the pdf, - leaving space before the content -. If I understand it correctly, breaking the lines is one fo the biggest issue here, so we should just let it go, lets try to scale it, if we can without changing the paper size. And I really appreciate the help, you are awesome! :)

Comment: That example PDF does not contain any textual content in PDF syntax, each page respectively only contains a single bitmap image (which shows something we read as text). To have any serious chance of re-flowing the layout, use PDFs with text drawn by PDF text showing instructions, not bitmaps. Scaling is doable of course.